# In Vim, why does searching "/A\n\zsB" work, but not syntax highlighting ":syn match Statement 'A\n\zsB'"?

Tags: vim, regex, syntax-highlighting

Assume the following text file:

```
A
B
```

Or in other words, a file containing only the string `A\nB`.

Let's see if I can match any `B` preceded by `A` and a newline. Simple enough. I can do this sucessfully with a `/`-search: `/A\n\zsB`. `B` is now highlighted.

But what I really want to do is apply syntax highlighting to `B`. Accordingly, I try `:syn match Statement 'A\n\zsB'`, but this does nothing. Anyone have an idea why?

(And just to pre-empt suggestions that I might not have turned on syntax highlighting on correctly: `:syn match Statement 'A\n\B'` *does* work as expected: `A` and `B` change color.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented behavior.  See `:help :syn-multi-line`, quoted here:

```
When using a start pattern with an offset, the start of the match is not
allowed to start in a following line.  The highlighting can start in a
following line though.  Using the "\zs" item also requires that the start
of the match doesn't move to another line.
```

The solution is to specify where the highlighting starts, rather than where the match starts. For example:

```
:syn match Statement 'A\nB'hs=e-1
```

See `:help :syn-pattern-offset`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! That's exactly the information I needed, yet seem to have overlooked.